# For next loop issue

Tags: vba, loops, for-loop

Gentleman,

I struggle with a small problem and get creasy because of them. I’d really appreciate your advice.

I have in a workbook a worksheet called “najemcy”. In this worksheet: **A2=3, A7=2, A12=1**. The following cells are merged: **A2:A6, A7:A11, A12:A16**. In column G are following values: **G2=550, G3=55, G7=650, G8=11 G12=550**.

The macro should find the last value in the column G in: **range A2:A6, A7:A11, A12:A16**. It means I expect to get 3 times msgbox with the address: **$G$4, $G$8, $G$12, but instead of $G$12 I get $G$1048576**.

```
Public Sub helpMe()

Dim najemcy As Worksheet
Dim pokoj As Range
Dim pokNr As Integer
Dim obecnyLok As Range

    For pokNr = 3 To 1 Step -1
        Set najemcy = Sheets("Najemcy")

        Set pokoj = najemcy.Range("A1:A100").Find(What:=pokNr, LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
'            MsgBox pokoj.Address

        Set obecnyLok = najemcy.Range(pokoj.Offset(0, 6).Address).End(xlDown)
        MsgBox obecnyLok.Address

    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Cześć ;) There is something weird you do in `Set obecnyLok`. `pokoj` is a cell in `najemcy` sheet. From this cell you go right 6 cells, take address from that cell and go to this address with `najemcy.Range`. So you just go back to the same cell. You can use this instead: `Set obecnyLok = pokoj.Offset(0, 6).End(xlDown)`.

Comment: Good point! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use .end(xlDown) it will go down until it hits a blank row but if the first row beneath the current one is blank it will just keep going.

One way around this would be to check if the next row down is blank before using .end(xlDown)

```
Public Sub helpMe()

Dim najemcy As Worksheet
Dim pokoj As Range
Dim pokNr As Integer
Dim obecnyLok As Range

For pokNr = 3 To 1 Step -1
    Set najemcy = Sheets("Najemcy")

    Set pokoj = najemcy.Range("A1:A100").Find(What:=pokNr, LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        'MsgBox pokoj.Address

    If najemcy.Range("G" & pokoj.Row + 1).Value = "" Then
        Set obecnyLok = najemcy.Range(pokoj.Offset(0, 6).Address)
    Else
        Set obecnyLok = najemcy.Range(pokoj.Offset(0, 6).Address).End(xlDown)
    End If
    MsgBox obecnyLok.Address

Next
End Sub
```